# Webdriverio Cucumberjs tests for a React Native app fails on AWS Device Farm - Socket hang up

Tags: react-native, cucumber, appium, webdriver-io, aws-device-farm

I'm writing End-to-ends tests for a React Native app using [WebdriverIo](https://webdriver.io/), [Appium](http://appium.io/) and [Cucumberjs](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/javascript/) and deploying the tests on the [AWS Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/).

The tests are working fine both on the Android simulator and on an actual real device. Though, on AWS, it throws errors such as `(node:3113) DeprecationWarning: Got: "options.rejectUnauthorized" is now deprecated, please use "options.https.rejectUnauthorized"` and `RequestError: socket hang up`. This is shown in more detail below:

```js
[DeviceFarm] echo "Start Appium Node test"
Start Appium Node test
[DeviceFarm] npm run only-one-test-aws

> e2e-cucumber-wdio-appium@1.0.0 only-one-test-aws /tmp/scratch0EgKio.scratch/test-packageFvDXet
> npx wdio ./wdio.android.conf.js --spec ./features/recarga/verificacacaoCodigoDeAcessoInvalido.feature


Execution of 1 spec files started at 2020-06-04T18:23:19.220Z

2020-06-04T18:23:19.223Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2020-06-04T18:23:19.254Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2020-06-04T18:23:19.256Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: ./wdio.android.conf.js,--spec,./features/recarga/verificacacaoCodigoDeAcessoInvalido.feature
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:23:20.961Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:23:21.062Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner:utils: init remote session
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:23:21.095Z INFO webdriverio: Initiate new session using the ./protocol-stub protocol
[0-0] RUNNING in undefined - /features/recarga/verificacacaoCodigoDeAcessoInvalido.feature
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:23:22.697Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner:utils: init remote session
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:23:22.714Z INFO webdriverio: Initiate new session using the webdriver protocol
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:23:22.717Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:23:22.717Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
  capabilities: { alwaysMatch: {}, firstMatch: [ {} ] },
  desiredCapabilities: {}
}
[0-0] (node:3113) DeprecationWarning: Got: "options.rejectUnauthorized" is now deprecated, please use "options.https.rejectUnauthorized"
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:24:52.853Z WARN webdriver: Request timed out! Consider increasing the "connectionRetryTimeout" option.
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:24:52.856Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 1/3
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:24:52.857Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:24:52.857Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
  capabilities: { alwaysMatch: {}, firstMatch: [ {} ] },
  desiredCapabilities: {}
}
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:24:54.004Z DEBUG webdriver: request failed due to response error: unknown error
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:24:54.004Z WARN webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: end of central directory record signature not found
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:24:54.005Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 2/3
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:24:54.014Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:24:54.014Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
  capabilities: { alwaysMatch: {}, firstMatch: [ {} ] },
  desiredCapabilities: {}
}
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:24:54.030Z ERROR webdriver: RequestError: socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/tmp/scratch0EgKio.scratch/test-packageFvDXet/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:817:25)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:322:22)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/tmp/scratch0EgKio.scratch/test-packageFvDXet/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js:39:20)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:453:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:322:22)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1187:12)
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:608:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:453:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:322:22)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1187:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
[0-0] 2020-06-04T18:24:54.031Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
socket hang up
    at startWebDriverSession (/tmp/scratch0EgKio.scratch/test-packageFvDXet/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:45:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[0-0]  Error:  Failed to create session.
socket hang up
2020-06-04T18:24:54.147Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner: Runner 0-0 finished with exit code 1
[0-0] FAILED in undefined - /features/recarga/verificacacaoCodigoDeAcessoInvalido.feature
2020-06-04T18:24:54.148Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:  0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:01:34 

2020-06-04T18:24:54.164Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2020-06-04T18:24:54.416Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2020-06-04T18:24:54.417Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! e2e-cucumber-wdio-appium@1.0.0 only-one-test-aws: `npx wdio ./wdio.android.conf.js --spec ./features/recarga/verificacacaoCodigoDeAcessoInvalido.feature`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the e2e-cucumber-wdio-appium@1.0.0 only-one-test-aws script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/device-farm/.npm/_logs/2020-06-04T18_24_54_506Z-debug.log

[DEVICEFARM] ########### Entering phase post_test ###########


[DEVICEFARM] ########### Finish executing testspec ###########

[DEVICEFARM] ########### Setting upload permissions ###########


[DEVICEFARM] Tearing down your device. Your tests report will come shortly.
```

I also tried this [question's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61642870/aws-device-farm-react-native-appium-nodejs-webdriverio-tests-not-working) by installing the `webdriverio` and `@wdio/cli` dependencies globally, though it did not work to me.

PS: I've already been able to successfully perform tests on the AWS Device Farm using webdriverio and cucumber. Though, these errors started to show up for me recently and I still have no clue on how to solve them.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What does your test_spec file look like? Also, are the version of `webdriverio` and `appium` version you choose from your test_spec file compatible?

Comment: @TobeE thanks for the reply
I currently have a few `.feature` test spec files where each one of them are placed at a specific folder depending on their domain in the app, in a structure like the following: `<rootFolder>/features/login/login.feature` and `<rootFolder>/features/registration/registration.feature`.

You can also check at [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/psatler/a3d0f6f4ce9efa8432bf5574c728819d) the dependecies I'm using and the `wdio` configs.

I believe they are compatible. I'm using, both locally and on AWS, `appium 1.17.1` , `webdriverio 6.1.7`,  node `12.16.1`.

Comment: Can you try posting a run URL of a run where this issue occurs to the [AWS Device Farm forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193&start=0) to see if they can help there?